# C++ : Passing threadID to function anomaly

Tags: c++, multithreading, program-entry-point, pthread-join

I implemented a concurrent queue with two methods: **add** (enqueue) & **remove** (dequeue).

To test my implementation using 2 threads, I generated 10 (NUMBER_OF_OPERATIONS) random numbers between 0 and 1 in a method called getRandom(). This allows me to create different distribution of add and remove operations.

The **doWork** method splits up the work done by the number of threads.

**PROBLEM:** The threadID that I am passing in from the main function does not match the threadID that the doWork method receives. Here are some sample runs:

[Output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjd4V.png)

[Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkxyB.png)

```
 #define NUMBER_OF_THREADS 2
 #define NUMBER_OF_OPERATIONS 10

 int main () {

        BoundedQueue<int> bQ;
        std::vector<double> temp = getRandom();
        double* randomNumbers = &temp[0];
        std::thread myThreads[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];

        for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
            cout << "Thread " << i << " created.\n";
            myThreads[i] = std::thread ( [&] { bQ.doWork(randomNumbers, i); });
        }

        cout << "Main Thread\n";

        for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++) {
            if(myThreads[i].joinable()) myThreads[i].join();
        }   
        return 0;
    }

    template <class T> void BoundedQueue<T>::doWork (double randomNumbers[], int threadID) {

        cout << "Thread ID is " << threadID << "\n";
        srand(time(NULL));  
        int split = NUMBER_OF_OPERATIONS / NUMBER_OF_THREADS;   
        for (int i = threadID * split; i < (threadID * split) + split; i++) {
            if(randomNumbers[i] <= 0.5) {
                int numToAdd = rand() % 10 + 1;
                add(numToAdd);
            } 
            else {
                int numRemoved = remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line you're capturing `i` by reference:

```
myThreads[i] = std::thread ( [&] { bQ.doWork(randomNumbers, i); });
```

This means that when the other thread runs the lambda, it'll get the latest value of i, not the value when it was created. Capture it by value instead:

```
myThreads[i] = std::thread ( [&, i] { bQ.doWork(randomNumbers, i); });
```

Whats worse, as you've got unordered read and write to `i`, your current code has undefined behavoir. And the fact *i* may've gone out of scope on the main thread before the other thread reads it. This fix above fixes all these issues.

Comment: It worth mentioning explicitely, that there is a delay between thread spawning and thread executing thread function. And thread constructor returns control as soon, as thread is spawned, so you can actually change a lot of variables, before thread function will be run.

Comment: This did it. Thank you Mike!

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I am new to multi-threaded programming. Is that a source of concern here?

Comment: @John Yes. This is the reason, why capturing by reference leads to that behavior. Also, you can do this without lambda, if you want. This will work the same way: `std::thread( decltype(bQ)::doWork, std::ref(bQ), randomNumbers, i )`.